# How to Process.Start("url") & Resize Browser vb.net

Tags: vb.net, process.start

Im trying to click a button and start my process which is easy as you can see, but how can it start the browser at a 900,700 size? Thank you in advance, your inputs is highly appreciated :)

```
 Private Sub ChromeButton13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChromeButton13.Click
        Try
            If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please enter a number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Else
               Process.Start(My.Settings.browserpath, ("http://google.com/" & My.Settings.deflanguage & TextBox1.Text & "&hip=" & TextBox1.Text & "&hnc=0"))
                End If
        Catch ex As Exception
           'smelly feet
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start chrome with some commandline parameters to set the window size

in your case **--window-position=x,y** and **--window-size=w,h** could be usefull

More switches and info here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches

```
Process.Start(My.Settings.browserpath, String.Format(" --window-position={3},{4} --window-size={5},{6} http://google.com/{0}{1}&hip={2}&hnc=0", My.Settings.deflanguage, TextBox1.Text, TextBox1.Text, xPos, yPos, cWidth, cHeight))
```

Comment: Alright, how would I make that even work?

`Process.Start(My.Settings.browserpath,("--window-size=w,h"), ("http://google.com/" & My.Settings.deflanguage & TextBox1.Text & "&hip=" & TextBox1.Text & "&hnc=0"))`

Comment: Thank you david, sorry for the last minute responce, I will check this out later on today and see if I can get it to work, if so, it will work on my program. Again, thank you for your help :)